# Prevent Angular form submit when invalid AND using a form action URL

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a form with a URL `action` set.  When `form.$invalid` is `true` *(or `form.$valid` is `false`)* I want to make the form **NOT submit to the URL** and show the invalid form errors in the UI.

In my particular case here, I'm using a framework that provides an Angular Controller for me, where I do not have the ability to add/modify functions on it!  I need to be able to do this **only by making changes to the template**.

Here's what I have so far *(simplified)*

```
<form novalidate
      name="form"
      method="post"
      ng-attr-action="{{model.loginUrl}}"
      ng-submit="return form.$valid">

    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-danger' : form.$submitted && form.username.$invalid}">
        <input type="text"
                name="username"
                required
                class="form-control"
                ng-model="model.username">

        <div class="form-control-feedback" ng-if="form.$submitted && form.username.$invalid">
             A username is required!
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

A lot of what I've seen online says to do something like

`ng-submit="form.$valid && model.myCustomSubmitFn()"`

but that doesn't use a URL form `action`, and I do not have the ability to add a custom function with this framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular passes the [`$event`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit#usage) in the context of ng-submit. So you call `$event.preventDefault()`. Your `ng-submit` would change to

```
<form novalidate
      name="form"
      ng-attr-action="{{model.loginUrl}}"
      ng-submit="form.$invalid && $event.preventDefault();form.$submitted=true;"
      >
```

See [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3ytxFWXVOoqBYPX9J93J?p=preview).

Comment: Excellent, this seems to do exactly what I need here, thanks you!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was searching for that answer everywhere!

Answer (score 0):

**THE BELOW IS AN ANSWER THAT WILL *NOT* WORK FOR THIS QUESTION-- I AM ONLY LEAVING IT HERE SO NO ONE ELSE TRIES THIS AS THE SOLUTION**

Might [`ngDisabled`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) work for you in this case?

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Sign In</button>
```

Comment: Doing that would make the button unusable, thus the form would never be able to submit when invalid.  Since I **only** want to show message about invalid form items upon attempting to submit, doing this would make it so that the validation messages **never** display.

Comment: @ChrisBarr -- Ah, I gotcha-- this _is_ a tricky one.  Updated my answer to show it isn't valid, but I'll leave it so new visitors to your question have a little more historical context.

Comment: Your update with the huge text made me lol - thanks for the input though!

Comment: Hahaha, no problem.  I should've just made a comment rather than post an answer, but I got cocky.

Comment: @ModarNa I explained above in my first comment.  it will prevent form submission, but that is not what I want to do and it will not provide the user experience that I want.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly a tricky situation since you only have access to edit the template. I'm not seeing an "angular" way to solve your problem with being able to edit the controller. Luckily though, this can be solved in the template alone with some vanilla JavaScript.

Try adding an `onclick` event handler to your button that prevents form submission if your form's input(s) do not match your validation criteria.

```
<button type="submit" onclick="if(form.username.value.length < 1) { event.preventDefault(); }">Sign In</button>
```

I'm not incredibly proud of this solution and it will certainly get dirty if you have more than one input in your form, however it looks like the only work-around for your unfortunate situation.

Comment: Will this work when the user presses the enter key?  It seems like this would only have an effect when the user presses the button with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

### Reactive Forms

If you wanted to declair this in the HTML of your reactive form you can simply do something like this:...

`<form [formGroup]="formGroupVar" (ngSubmit)="formGroupVar.valid ?
 submitFunc() : null" novalidate>...</form>`

So what you are doing is making your `(ngSubmit)` a ternary operator, the comparison would be your `formGroupVar.valid`, when true, you would execute your submitFunc() else null.

NOTE: There is no reason why you wouldn't just do this in your TypeScript file, it would make sense to keep your HTML as 'clean' as possible, but that doesn't mean it is not possible!